# Permission denied [Errno 13] from savefig() called makegraph.py, script is invoked from a C# Process.Class

Tags: python, c#, permissions

I have this problem of calling the script from Process in C# THE SECOND TIME I run the script with the same parameters. I am getting a permission denied, and have something to do with me overriding the last version of the .png I am saving from savefig() however when I run the script in terminal, no error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File (full-path)..\\net6.0-windows\\MakeGraph.py\"
\\net6.0-windows\\MakeGraph.py\", line 26, in savefig\r\n plt.savefig(file)
\\site-packages\\PIL\\Image.py\", line 2428, in save
\r\n    fp = builtins.open(filename, \"w+b\")\r\nPermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Furthermore, I have done the following recommendations:

- change folder settings to Documents (done)
- check if path exist (it does)
- check if destination path is file (it is)
- If I restart my C# project, I am able to override it once before making a permission denied
- If I change name of the file "newname.png" it allows me to create that but running it again --> Permission denied.

Is there a way to tell the script from C# Process that it has permission to override or even delete files?

My code looks the following:

```cs
string fileName = csv_input.Text;
string folderName = KgBox.Text;

ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
PSI.FileName = @python_exe;

PSI.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", sript_py, fileName, folderName);
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
try
{
    using (Process? p = Process.Start(PSI))
    {
        p.WaitForExit();
        status_from_script += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        status_from_script += p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        ErrorBox.Text += status_from_script;
    }
}
```

And my python script:

```py
def savefig(dataframe, title):
plt.plot(dataframe)
plt.xlabel("data point")
plt.ylabel("Acceleration (m/s^2)")
plt.title(title)
y = [1,-30,-60,-90,-120, -150, -180, -210, -240, -270, -300, -330]
plt.yticks(y)
file = save_path + "\\"+ csv_folder + ".png"
print(file)
plt.savefig(file)
plt.close()
print("DONE")
```

EDITED:
I have found out it has something to do with the process not being closed when running the script (the file is in another process)